# Combinations between one element of each list of combinations

Tags: python

I have about 12 lists `[a, b, c, ... , z]` with arbitrary elements and i´ve got a series of combinations through `itertools.combinations(iterable, n)` resulting in lists of combinations that match each of the original list.

The great deal now is to get a list with all the possible combinations, picking one element(combination) of each combinations list.

One simplified exemple would be:

```
A = [a,b,c]
B = [d,e,f]
C = [g,h,i]

my_iterable = [A, B, C]
```

And the output should be:

```
>>> foo(my_iterable)
(a,d,g), (a,d,h), (a,d,i), (a,e,g), (a,e,h), ... , (c,f,i)
```

The input iterables, e.g. 'A, B & C', may have variable lengths and `foo()` may be a generator function.

Comment: `itertools.product(A, B, C)`  for your example

Answer (score 0):

```
A = ['a','b','c']
B = ['d','e','f']
C = ['g','h','i']

l = [(a, b, c) for a in A for b in B for c in C]
print(l)
```

out:

```
[('a', 'd', 'g'), ('a', 'd', 'h'), ('a', 'd', 'i'), ('a', 'e', 'g'), ('a', 'e', 'h'), ('a', 'e', 'i'), ('a', 'f', 'g'), ('a', 'f', 'h'), ('a', 'f', 'i'), ('b', 'd', 'g'), ('b', 'd', 'h'), ('b', 'd', 'i'), ('b', 'e', 'g'), ('b', 'e', 'h'), ('b', 'e', 'i'), ('b', 'f', 'g'), ('b', 'f', 'h'), ('b', 'f', 'i'), ('c', 'd', 'g'), ('c', 'd', 'h'), ('c', 'd', 'i'), ('c', 'e', 'g'), ('c', 'e', 'h'), ('c', 'e', 'i'), ('c', 'f', 'g'), ('c', 'f', 'h'), ('c', 'f', 'i')]
```